# Using vue-virtual-scroller not showing

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying out https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller but I cannot get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

I use `pug / jade` for server-side `HTML` rendering. I don't receive any error messages but nothing gets rendered...

`Pug / Jade`

```
#test

  recyclescroller.scroller(:items='active_projects' :item-size='32' key-field='id' v-slot='{ item }')
    
    .user
         | {{ item.name }}
```

`CSS`

```
.user {
  height: 32%;
  padding: 0 12px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

`javascript`

```
Vue.component('RecycleScroller', VueVirtualScroller.RecycleScroller)

test = new Vue({

    el: '#test',

    data: {
           active_projects        : [{name : 'test'}]
          }
})
```

Comment: Did you try to inspect it with vue-devtool? What does it show? an empty div?

Comment: Tried to install the devtools... but for some reason it won't run (says that vue is in production mode...)

Answer (score 1):

When you use Recyclescroller you should inside each item has **`id`**

Because the **`uniqueness`** of the item is done by using the **`id`**

Your list should look like this :

```js
data () {
        return {
            active_projects: [
                {
                    name: 'test', id: 1
                },
                {
                    name: 'test', id: 2
                },
                {
                    name: 'test', id: 3
                },
                {
                    name: 'test', id: 4
                },
            ]
        }
    }
```

### [Doc - Important notes](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-virtual-scroller#recyclescroller)

If the items are objects, the scroller needs to be able to identify them. By default it will look for an **`id`** field on the items. This can be configured with the **`keyField`** prop if you are using another field name.